# Invalid Syntax on this code, no idea how to fix

Tags: python, pygame

No idea why the syntax is invalid, anyone have an idea?  It says the two bottom lines of code in particular have invalid syntax.  This is probably embarassingly simple to fix, so please have mercy on my soul.

I haven't tried anything because it's an extremely basic problem and I'm probably just bad at coding

```py
import pygame
import sys
import time
pygame.init()

(width, height) = (1920, 1080)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('fat')

background_colour = pygame.Color('white')
color = pygame.Color('dodgerblue2')
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 100)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
text = ''

while running:


    # handle events and user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if (event.key >= pygame.K_SPACE and event.key <= pygame.K_z):
                # Append key-stroke's character
                text += event.unicode
            elif (event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE):
                text = text[:-1]
            elif (event.key == pygame.K_RETURN): 
                #print("interpret(text) - NOT IMPLEMENTED")
                text = ""
        if len(text) > 20:
            text = text[:-1]
    # repaint the screen
    screen.fill(background_colour)
    txt_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
    screen.blit(txt_surface, (50, 100))
    response = font.render(Room.defaultprompt, True, color)
    screen.blit((response,(80, 150))

clock.tick_busy_loop(60)  # limit FPS   
display.flip()
```

The code did, but no longer, takes what the user types and presents it onto the screen.  It stopped working after I tried to make pygame draw another line of text.  (btw I know that Room.defaultprompt is undefined but that's because the rest of the code just isn't in the post)

Comment: Paste the error so we can help.

Comment: The line `screen.blit((response,(80, 150))` has an unmatched open paren.

Comment: {
 "resource": "-----------------------",
 "owner": "python",
 "code": "syntax-error",
 "severity": 8,
 "message": "invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 72)",
 "source": "pylint",
 "startLineNumber": 72,
 "startColumn": 1,
 "endLineNumber": 72,
 "endColumn": 1
}

Comment: Add a parenthesis to screen.blit,  screen.blit((response,(80, 150)))

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Why would you add an extra closing bracket? The correct way should be to remove the second open param

Comment: @Winston It would have been much better if you had edited your post and put the error in the question, properly formatted. That way, other people can read your question more easily.

Comment: Alright, I will do that next time.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself, missing parentheses are difficult for both humans and interpreters to spot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking closely to it, so an error on this line:

```
screen.blit((response,(80, 150))
```

When it should be:

```
screen.blit(response,(80, 150))
```

*@ErikXIII's answer is little different*

Comment: Please don't add full answers to typos. They are not helpful for future readers, and adding answers will hinder [automatic deletion processes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).